# Camel Serialize MessageContentsList

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I receive a SOAP message to a CXF endpoint, with a Long and String value.
eg. [5, 'test']

The camel route receiving messages is already using dataformat=POJO
I need to send these parameters on ActiveMQ to another application.

If I use:

```
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
```

The logs show the body contains 5 only.  'test' is not sent.

I tried converting to a POJO before converting to a String, but I can't find proper documentation on making TypeConverters, (seriously, who can read [this](http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html)  and figure out actual code from it?)

eg.

```
<convertBodyTo type="com.company.InfoPojo"/>
<convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
```

If I try to just forward the CXF data to the queue without any converting, I get:

> Failed to extract body due to: javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to
>   build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker.
>   Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class
>   org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList! This class is not allowed
>   to be serialized. Add package with
>   'org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES' system property..

Anyone know what the best option here is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should marshal the parameters to XML or JSON (or any other format that takes your fancy) before sending them to the queue.  The consumer will then need to unmarshal them.

No need to mess around with type converters.  Camel's data formats make this really easy: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/readme.adoc#data-formats

JSON: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/json.adoc

JAXB: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jaxb/src/main/docs/jaxb-dataformat.adoc

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but am having trouble verifying. I keep getting bizarre results.

If I use XStream marshalling, it complains "Data format 'xstream' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath" despite it being on the classpath, and an installed feature in Fuse.

If I use JAXB, it sends a byte[].  When I convert to String, it contains 'test'.  Now it's not sending the 5.  Weird.

Comment: Some of the data types need to be registered in your spring or blueprint before you can use them, if they need a little configuration.  I would create a POJO with a `long` and `String` property, populate that from the MCL then marshal the POJO.  The AMQ component is clever enough to do the marshalling itself if you use JAXB.

Comment: I managed to solve it using my own half-ass solution.  Thanks for the help though.   I'll post my answer, and give you an upvote.  I just wasn't able to get it working in any standard way.

Answer (score 0):

Made a bean and sent to the bean:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    log.info("Converting CXF values for queue.");
    Object[] args = exchange.getIn().getBody(Object[].class);
    patientKey = String.valueOf((Long)args[0]);
    destinationUrl = (String)args[1];
    exchange.getOut().setBody(new String(patientKey + "|" + destinationUrl));
}
```

Comment: Cool, just hope that `patientKey` or `destinationUrl` never contain a pipe character!